# Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Learning Ruby on rails from Michael Hartl 
I am following the book and have come across a problem when inserting an image, the error that is produced is here

```
SyntaxError in Pages#home
```

Showing /Users/richardhardesty/Sites/rails_projects/beginning/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #17 raised:

```
/Users/richardhardesty/Sites/rails_projects/beginning/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...pend= ( image_tag('logo.png'  :alt =>'Sample App'  :class =>...
...                               ^
/Users/richardhardesty/Sites/rails_projects/beginning/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...go.png'  :alt =>'Sample App'  :class =>"round" ) );@output_b...
...                               ^
/Users/richardhardesty/Sites/rails_projects/beginning/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...mple App'  :class =>"round" ) );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
...                               ^
```

Extracted source (around line #17):

```
14:     <body>
15:         <div class="container">
16:             <header>
17:                 <%= image_tag('logo.png'  :alt =>'Sample App'  :class =>"round" ) %>
18:             <nav class="round">
19:                 <ul>
20:                     <li><%= link_to "Home", '#' %></li>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

I have tried altering the the quotes and brckets and different errors are listed but the problem doesn't go away.
Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need commas between the arguments in the `image_tag` method:

```
 <%= image_tag('logo.png', :alt =>'Sample App', :class =>"round" ) %>
```

Comment: Thank you for my formatting and thanks for the answer ,,,,hey it works :-)